# Accessing a InArgument from a CodeActivity()

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I would love your help. I am new to Workflow and I have define some InArguments in my workflow that I want to access in different activities. In my test project I have a InArgument named "Text" which has a default value.  I am trying to access this value within my activity by doing this.

```
 public InArgument<String> Text { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.{1} Start Date Time", MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Eric the text is: {0}", Text.Get(context)));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I have created the local InArgument with the same name as the InArgument global to the workflow. When I do the get, the value that it is returning is null. I tried to access the context object but have been unable to get to the property's value (although I saw the property's name). I apologize if this is trivial, but I would love your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the activity looks fine. What for expression did you put in the Text property when you added the activity to your workflow? Because that determines the value you read, there is no default value for an InArgument that is not tied to something in the workflow.

Comment: Maurice, Thank you for the response.  That worked...however...I am trying to have the I have a couple of questions on why it worked.  There is a default value in the arguments portion of the workflow.  If I need to set the value in the designer for each activity, what is the point of the default value for the workflow?

Comment: Also, I am trying to give the user the ability to define some parameters that will alter the direction of the workflow, are InArguments the wrong thing to use.

Comment: InArgument are just that for the specific activity or workflow. If you want to have an activity InArgument use a workflow InArgument, or Variable, you need to do so through a VB expression. And yes workflow InArguments are the way to get user values into a workflow when it starts.